# what happens in ASP Classic when you multiply a value that cannot be parsed as an integer by an integer?

Tags: asp-classic, type-conversion

suppose you have something like:

```
Dim x, y
x = Request("x")
y = x * 2
```

If x cannot be parsed as an integer, will there be an exception or will the resulting expression be parsed as an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpreter will try to evaluate `x` as number. Code works if value is numeric (float or integer), else a type mismatch error occurs.

Comment: True, but not accurate. It will try to evaluate the value of Request item that `x` is its key. Sorry to be picky, but want things to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard No need to be sorry :) I meant `x` the variable one, not the key. Here's what I meant : with `x = Request("x")`, `x` assigned to Request("x") (picky note: Suppose the Request is a Post or QueryString Collection. Request("x") returns a comma-delimited string of `IStringList` due to the index was not specified.). Now the variable `x` is a string even if value is numeric. With `y = x * 2`, `x`(string) will be evaluate as number.

Comment: Cheers, guess I just had a blonde moment. :)